# Неразрывная строка

Tags: вёрстка, html, css

Предположим, у меня на странице есть какой-нибудь inline-элемент (ну, давайте для определённости `<span>`). В нём несколько слов текста.

Как сделать так, чтобы при уменьшении окна, текст внутри `span`'а не переносился по словам т.е. всегда оставался одной строкой?

*P.S. Костыли вроде использования неразрывных пробелов не предлагать.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap;">Some Text</span>
```

Comment: Как я только проглядел это свойство…